# React Native How to filter sectionlist data on the basis of id

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, flatlist, react-native-sectionlist

**this is the get api of sectionlist data**

const getAllMatches = async () => {

```
await fetch(APIS?.Matches, {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    Authorization: user,
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
})
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(({matches}) => {
    setAllMatches(matches);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    return console.error(error);
  });
```

};

Comment: you want to filter then or sort them?

Comment: i want to filter.

Answer (score 0):

just in your code when setting matches use:

`setAllMatches(matches.filter((item,index)=>item.category=="fruits");`

in this case we are putting matches with the category fruits, you can adjust accordingly